# Loading Data from a TEXT file to a JSP Servlet page

Tags: java, jsp, io

I am new to using JSP but I pretty familiar with Java and I have a strange occurrence happening.

I have a file "customer.txt" that I am reading one record from (there is only one record)

and using the StringTokenizer class I am paring out the elements, I then want to load each element into my HTML Input text boxes and display ... the system is locking up and the message is "waiting for Local Host" ... is what I am doing not allowed or wrong? Please let me know

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class CustProfile extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    // Get Customer Information based on CustId
    int count = 1;
    String id = null;
    String name = null;
    String addr1 = null;
    String addr2 = null;
    String city = null;
    String state = null;
    String zip = null;
    String phone = null;
    String tvplan = null;
    String intplan = null;
    String line;
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/customer.txt");
    FileReader f = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
    line = b.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

           while (s.hasMoreElements()) {
              id = s.nextElement().toString();
              name = s.nextElement().toString();
              addr1 = s.nextElement().toString();
              addr2 = s.nextElement().toString();
              city = s.nextElement().toString();
              state = s.nextElement().toString();
              zip = s.nextElement().toString();
              phone = s.nextElement().toString();
              tvplan = s.nextElement().toString();
              intplan = s.nextElement().toString();

}
     }
       // Whether or not the customer changed the order, show
    // order status.
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Customer Profile Information";
    String MainPageURL =
          response.encodeURL("/csj/Products.html");
    String docType =
      "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
      "Transitional//EN\">\n";
    out.println(docType +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                "<H1 ALIGN=\"CENTER\">" + title + "</H1>");

    out.println("<BR>" +
        "<BR>" +
        "<a href=" + MainPageURL + ">Previous Page</a>");  

        out.println
          ("<Form>\n" +   
          "<CENTER>" +
            "Please Enter the following Information:\n" +
            "<TABLE>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Name:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_name\" value=" + name + "  </input>\n" +
            "</TR>" +

            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Street Address:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Add1\" value=" + addr1 + " </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Apt or Suite:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Add2\" value=" + addr2 + " </input>\n" + 
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "City:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_City\" value=" + city + "</input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "State:" +
            "</TD><TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_state\" value=" + state + "</input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Zip Code:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Zip\" value=" + zip + "</input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Phone Number:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
             "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Phone\" value=" + phone + " </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Cable Plan:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_tvPlan\" value=" + tvplan + "</input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Internet Plan:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_IntPlan\" value=" + intplan + "</input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<TABLE>" +


            "</CENTER>" +
            "</Form>"  );




        String updateURL =
          response.encodeURL("/csj/UpdateCust");
        // "Proceed to Checkout" button below table
        out.println
          ("</TABLE>\n" +
           "<FORM ACTION=\"" + updateURL + "\">\n" +
           "<BIG><CENTER>\n" +
           "<INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"\n" +
           "       VALUE=\"Update Profile\">\n" +

           "</CENTER></BIG>" +
           "</FORM>");


      out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sc.getRealPath()` expect the `URL` path. It will convert URL path to real path. So, following statement is not correct.

```
    String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/customer.txt");
```

Change your code like:

```
    String path = sc.getRealPath("/");// Here you will get valid path.
    FileReader f = new FileReader(path+"/WEB-INF/customer.txt");
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
   .............
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time, I don't quite understand ... how do I remedy to the FileReader to find my file?

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, See my edited answer. hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I pretty certain it is finding the file, but I am looping or I am hung up. I am writing this code in notepad, for an assignment so I cannot debug. My concern was that I was doing something I am not supposed to.